# Need to add editable text (metadata) for new as well as previously uploaded images

Tags: aws-sdk, fine-uploader

I need to add editable text field to have 'Caption' for each uploaded file. User may provide Captions at the time of upload;but, need option to provide Captions after uploading all of their images or update captions on already uploaded images.

I was able to get the get Caption data and set that as metadata in S3 using below:

JS segment:

```
callbacks: {            
    onUpload: function(id, fileName) {          
        var caption = document.getElementById('caption').value;
        this.setParams({'caption':caption});
    }
}
```

Template:

```
<script type="text/template" id="qq-template-manual-trigger-section1">
    <div class="qq-uploader-selector qq-uploader" qq-drop-area-text="Drop files here">
    <div class="qq-total-progress-bar-container-selector qq-total-progress-bar-container">
        <div role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="0" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" class="qq-total-progress-bar-selector qq-progress-bar qq-total-progress-bar"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="qq-upload-drop-area-selector qq-upload-drop-area" qq-hide-dropzone>
        <span class="qq-upload-drop-area-text-selector"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="buttons">
        <div class="qq-upload-button-selector qq-upload-button">
            <div>Select files</div>
        </div>
        <button type="button" id="trigger-upload-section1" class="btn btn-primary">
            <i class="icon-upload icon-white"></i> Upload
        </button>
    </div>
    <span class="qq-drop-processing-selector qq-drop-processing">
        <span>Processing dropped files...</span>
        <span class="qq-drop-processing-spinner-selector qq-drop-processing-spinner"></span>
    </span>
    <ul class="qq-upload-list-selector qq-upload-list" aria-live="polite" aria-relevant="additions removals">
        <li>
            <div class="qq-progress-bar-container-selector">
                <div role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="0" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" class="qq-progress-bar-selector qq-progress-bar"></div>
            </div>
            <span class="qq-upload-spinner-selector qq-upload-spinner"></span>
            <img class="qq-thumbnail-selector" qq-max-size="100" qq-server-scale>
            <span class="qq-upload-file-selector qq-upload-file"></span>
            <span class="qq-edit-filename-icon-selector qq-edit-filename-icon qq-editable" aria-label="Edit filename"></span>
            <input class="qq-edit-filename-selector qq-edit-filename" tabindex="0" type="text">
            <span class="qq-upload-caption-selector qq-upload-caption"></span>
            <span class="qq-edit-caption-icon-selector qq-edit-caption-icon qq-editable" aria-label="Edit caption"></span>
            <input class="qq-edit-caption-selector qq-edit-caption qq-editing" placeholder="Caption  here ..." tabindex="0" type="text" id="caption">
            <span class="qq-upload-size-selector qq-upload-size"></span>
            <button type="button" class="qq-btn qq-upload-cancel-selector qq-upload-cancel">Cancel</button>
            <button type="button" class="qq-btn qq-upload-retry-selector qq-upload-retry">Retry</button>
            <button type="button" class="qq-btn qq-upload-delete-selector qq-upload-delete">Delete</button>                    
            <span role="status" class="qq-upload-status-text-selector qq-upload-status-text"></span>
        </li>
    </ul>

    <dialog class="qq-alert-dialog-selector">
        <div class="qq-dialog-message-selector"></div>
        <div class="qq-dialog-buttons">
            <button type="button" class="qq-cancel-button-selector">Close</button>
        </div>
    </dialog>

    <dialog class="qq-confirm-dialog-selector">
        <div class="qq-dialog-message-selector"></div>
        <div class="qq-dialog-buttons">
            <button type="button" class="qq-cancel-button-selector">No</button>
            <button type="button" class="qq-ok-button-selector">Yes</button>
        </div>
    </dialog>

    <dialog class="qq-prompt-dialog-selector">
        <div class="qq-dialog-message-selector"></div>
        <input type="text">
        <div class="qq-dialog-buttons">
            <button type="button" class="qq-cancel-button-selector">Cancel</button>
            <button type="button" class="qq-ok-button-selector">Ok</button>
        </div>
    </dialog>
</div>
</script>
```

In a effort to make Caption input field to behave/function like filename, I have defined following Style

```
INPUT.qq-edit-caption {
    position: absolute;
    opacity: 0;
    filter: alpha(opacity=0);
    z-index: -1;
    -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=0)";
}
.qq-edit-caption-icon.qq-editable {
    display: inline-block;
    cursor: pointer;
}
INPUT.qq-edit-caption.qq-editing {
    position: static;
    height: 28px;
    padding: 0 8px;
    margin-right: 10px;
    margin-bottom: -5px;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-radius: 2px;
    font-size: 16px;

    opacity: 1;
    filter: alpha(opacity=100);
    -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=100)";
}

.qq-edit-caption-icon {
    display: none;
    background: url("edit.gif");
    width: 15px;
    height: 15px;
    vertical-align: text-bottom;
    margin-right: 16px;
}
```

My questions and advice needed for the following:

1. I tried my best to make Caption field to behave like filename such
   as onclick Edit text field will appear. Defined caption field very
   similar to filename. Not sure how I can apply style 'qq-editing' to edit Caption? And, apply 'qq-hide' as needed. Any help is much appreciated.
2. How can user edit Caption on previously uploaded files?
   I tried few hack steps (one being, tried to use Delete endpoint by passing diff param) to send Caption to server and nothing is
   working for me; Really need expert advise on how I can use edit/update caption already uploaded files .

Comment: Please show HTML that demonstrates exactly what the relevant markup looks like, and any JS that is relevant as well.

Comment: I am in research mode; no implementation started yet. In term of feature, it would act like Edit fine name and update; My edit file name is not working yet, if I see issue will post another question. The new text field is essentially to add user text/notes for the file. I am imaging it would have same look n feel like manually starting the upload after changing the fine names; but, I need that look n feel and function after the upload as well (I mean initFiles).

Comment: There are many options. You can use the form support feature, or pass the input value to Fine Uploader via `setParams`. Once you have some actual code to show, i'll be able to help more.

Comment: Sure and I will make some progress.

Comment: I wanted to add text input field right next to filename and I added following the template and style respectively. My goal s to send a note/caption to the server. I my skills around the style is very low! The issue is I can make it editable like finename. autoupload is false. What other hooks I need to ad to make it editable?

Comment: <span class="qq-edit-filename-icon-selector qq-edit-filename-icon" aria-label="Edit filename"></span>
                    <input class="qq-edit-filename-selector qq-edit-filename" tabindex="0" type="text">
     <span class="qq-edit-caption-icon-selector qq-edit-caption-icon" aria-label="Edit caption"></span>
                    <input class="qq-edit-caption-selector qq-edit-caption" tabindex="0" type="text">

Comment: INPUT.qq-edit-caption {   
//same as filename
}
.qq-edit-caption-icon.qq-editable { 
//same as filename   
}
INPUT.qq-edit-caption.qq-editing {    
//same as filename
}
.qq-edit-caption-icon {   
//same as filename
}

Comment: Please edit your question to include HTML and JavaScript that shows your attempt, as well as any details needed to provide assistance. Please don't post this code as one long string of text in comments.

Comment: I have updated my question with HTML template and JS; I am trying have text input called caption for each uploaded file and pass that to server. Trying really learn fine uploader and looks like big learning curve for me. Any help is much appreciated to get me to next step.

Comment: So, I have new text input field called 'caption' in the markup with default value 'captionXX'; this results in setting x-amz-meta-caption = captionXX, which is awesome; my question is how to make caption input field as user entered value (dynamic); also, how make same behavior with init files list?

Comment: Also,is it possible to have custom  function like onEditingStatusChange (pasted on the question section)? How can I get id of previously uploaded files (Init File List) ?

Comment: Sorry, there are far too many questions here. I'm going to focus on what you have posted in original question when I get some time this week.

Comment: Ray, I was fire fighting this issue to get this resolved by the weekend. Made good progress, but could not complete it. I have updated the original question to be precise so you can get to the advice hopefully quickly!

Comment: You already have [an open question regarding changing the filename for a previously uploaded file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36365148/in-fine-uploader-how-to-edit-file-names-that-are-uploaded-in-previous-sessions), so I won't address that here. As far as your first question, I'm not able to provide any help given the "template segment" you have provided. You'll need to provide the _entire_ template, not a "segment".

Comment: OK and updated the template and will update 2nd question in other thead.