# setting value to deletingStatusText is not working in fineuploader

Tags: aws-sdk, fine-uploader

This a follow up [question from.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36365148/in-fine-uploader-how-to-edit-update-s3-file-metadata-for-files-that-are-uploade?noredirect=1#comment60495891_36365148)

I am trying to utilize the current Delete process for Caption Update(in my case). The implementation works,but statusText still remains as default (Deleting....). As per the answer in the above link, I  tried to set deletingStatusText= 'Updating...' in DeleteFile option. And, I have alert statement in the DeleteFile. Even before displaying the alert, statusText already shows 'Deleting...' please see the [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/37qfO.jpg).

It is possible that I am missing something bit I can not figure out what is missing. Do I need set status any other place ?

JS

```
var isCaptionUpdate = false;
var statusText = "Deleting...";
var captionValue = "";
function captionUpdate(){
    isCaptionUpdate = true; 
    statusText = "Updating..."; 
};
var manualUploaderSection1 = new qq.s3.FineUploader({
    element: document.getElementById('fine-uploader-manual-trigger-section1'),
    template: 'qq-template-manual-trigger-section1',
    autoUpload: false,
    debug: true,
    request: {
        endpoint: "http://xx_my_bucket_xx.s3.amazonaws.com",
        accessKey: "AKIAIAABIA",        
    },
    signature: {
        endpoint: "http://localhost/app/ci/php-s3-server/endpoint-cors.php"
    },
    uploadSuccess: {
        endpoint: "http://localhost/app/ci/php-s3-server/endpoint-cors.php?success",
        params: {
            isBrowserPreviewCapable: qq.supportedFeatures.imagePreviews
        }
    },
    session: {
        endpoint: "http://localhost/app/ci/php-s3-server/endpoint-cors.php?filelist"
    },
    iframeSupport: {
        localBlankPagePath: "success.html"
    },
    cors: {
        expected: true
    },
    chunking: {
        enabled: true
    },
    resume: {
        enabled: true
    },
    deleteFile: {
        enabled: true,
        method: "POST",
        endpoint: "http://localhost/app/ci/php-s3-server/endpoint-cors.php",
        deletingStatusText: statusText,
        params: {
            qqcaption: function(id, name) {
                alert(statusText);
                if (isCaptionUpdate === true) {
                    isCaptionUpdate = false; 
                    return captionValue;
                }
            }
        }
    },
    validation: {
        itemLimit: 5,
        sizeLimit: 15000000
    },
    thumbnails: {
        placeholders: {
            notAvailablePath: "http://localhost/app/ci/s3.fine-uploader/placeholders/not_available-generic.png",
            waitingPath: "http://localhost/app/ci/s3.fine-uploader/placeholders/waiting-generic.png"
        }
    },
    callbacks: {
        onComplete: function(id, name, response) {
            var previewLink = qq(this.getItemByFileId(id)).getByClass('preview-link')[0];

            if (response.success) {
                previewLink.setAttribute("href", response.tempLink)
            }
        },
        onUpload: function(id, fileName) {      
            captionValue = qq(this.getItemByFileId(id)).getByClass('qq-edit-caption')[0].value;
            this.setParams({'qqcaption':captionValue});
        },
        onDelete: function(id) {
            captionValue = qq(this.getItemByFileId(id)).getByClass('qq-edit-caption')[0].value;
        }
    }    
});

qq(document.getElementById("trigger-upload-section1")).attach("click", function() {
    manualUploaderSection1.uploadStoredFiles();
});
```

Comment: I am wondering why this question not attempted to answer? Why this question is -1?

Comment: resolved with following dom manipulation

Comment: onDelete: function(id) {
         captionValue = qq(this.getItemByFileId(id)).getByClass('qq-edit-caption')[0].value;
         
         //change sttaus to 'Updating..' if it is Caption update
         var statusSpan = qq(this.getItemByFileId(id)).getByClass('qq-upload-status-text')[0];
         if (isCaptionUpdate === true) {
       if (statusSpan.innerText) {
        statusSpan.innerText = statusText;
       }
       else if (statusSpan.textContent) {
        statusSpan.textContent = statusText;   
       }
         }
        },

Comment: Please don't post long strings of code in a comment - it's nearly impossible to read. This answer should be posted as an answer.